Distribution of states of H$_2$ gas for a given temperature
How can I calculate the population distribution of vibrational and rotational states of H$_2$ gas, for any given temperature? I think the vibrational states are more important, since the rotational states act as perturbations on the energy levels of the vibrational states. I believe I should start from the Boltzmann distribution, which implies that regardless of temperature the distribution is a decaying exponential with energy. But, that would suggest no matter the temperature, lower energy states are always more probable. Am I missing something? Or is it as simple as figuring out the energy of each $i^{th}$ state and plotting $P(E_i) \propto e^{\frac{-E_i}{k_BT}}$?

So are you ignoring the rotational states or not? The degeneracy of rotational states is $2J+1$, which causes the distribution to be "peaked." You are correct that the vibrational states follow a consistent exponential decay, however.

@MattHanson I would like to have a solution that does not ignore the rotational states; I just mentioned that as a first step approximation. What would the solution look like taking into account the rotational states?

The total energy for the vibrations and rotations is just the sum of the vibrational and rotational energies,
\begin{gather*}
E = E_n + F_{n,J}
\end{gather*}
where $E_n$ is the vibrational energy and $F_{n,J}$ is the rovibrationally corrected rotational energy. Based on the data at NIST, the hydrogen atom has a harmonic frequency $\omega_e = 4401$ cm$^{-1}$ with an anharmonicity constant of $x_e = 0.0276$. Given that the energies of the Morse oscillator (a good approximation for the diatomic vibrations) are,
\begin{gather*}
E_n = \omega_e \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right) - \omega_e x_e \left( n + \frac{1}{2} \right)^2 
\end{gather*}
Given that at a room temperature of 298 K the value of $k_BT \approx 207$ cm$^{-1}$, then the Boltzmann distribution,
\begin{gather*}
P(E_n) \propto e^{-\frac{E_n}{k_BT}}
\end{gather*}
has 0.999999998 probability of occupying the ground vibrational state $E_0$. We will thus proceed with the assumption that the ground state vibration is the only one normally occupied. The rotational constant is $B = 60.85$ cm$^{-1}$ and the rovibrational coupling constant is $\alpha_e = 3.062$ cm$^{-1}$. The rotational energies can then be approximated as,
\begin{gather*}
F_{n,J} \approx BJ(J+1) - \alpha_e J(J+1)\left( n+\frac{1}{2} \right)
\end{gather*}
where we will let $n=0$. The part you are missing that could make a difference is that the Boltzmann distribution has a prefactor for the degeneracy or multiplicity of the state. For the rotational states this factor is $2J+1$, giving the distribution,
\begin{gather*}
P(F_{n,J}) \propto (2J+1)e^{-\frac{F_{n,J}}{k_BT}}
\end{gather*}
This gives the following distributions of the energies, which looks somewhat like a distorted exponential decay. As you can see, the highest probability rotational state also has $J=0$, which means that the ground electronic, vibrational, and rotational state is the overall most probable state of the hydrogen atom at room temperature. This behavior of the rotational states differs for other molecules. For instance, CO has a peak in its rotational Boltzmann distribution at about $J = 7$.


Thank you so much! I still have a few questions though. (1) What do you mean that the energy is "rovibrationally corrected"? (2) Is 'n' in your equations above the index for the vibrational state and 'J' is the rotational state? (3) In my case, I am not considering room temperature, so I can't just say that n=0 necessarily. (4) I am not seeing where you have added a prefactor representing the multiplicity in your last equation. Why do we have to consider the multiplicities for the rotational states, but not for the vibrational states?

Good question! The rovibrational coupling correction accounts for the fact that vibrations and rotations are not truly independent. Namely, if the anharmonicity of the bond length is taken into account, the expected bond length increases with $n$ (the vibrational quantum number) and the rotational energies are slightly suppressed from the expected values. The constant $\alpha_e$ accounts for this coupling approximately. And the entire analysis that I provided works for any temperatures; replace the T in the equations with yours. The multiplicity of the diatomic vibrational states is just 1.

Thank you, that makes sense. Another question I am curious about is where the omega comes from in your second equation. If it has units of cm^-1, and n is a unitless integer, then I don't see how we are getting units of energy.

(And similarly for the expression for rotational energy, if B has units of cm^-1, how are we getting energy units?)

Wave numbers (inverse centimeters) are a weird unit of energy. You can convert them with the formula $E=hc\tilde{\nu}$ where the tilde denotes the quantity in wave numbers and $c$ is the speed of light.

Great, thank you! That's what I ended up doing for omega, and since B has the same units I should have realized I could convert in the same way. Thanks so much for your help.

Of course! And if this answer and commentary resolved your issues I would appreciate the accepted answer as well.

It might be good to mention that molecular hydrogen comes in ortho and para form which can be considered as different species under most circumstances and thus two different Boltzmann distributions are required to describe them.

That’s fair, but I wanted to tackle this from a relatively simple standpoint!
